# Compile error: byref argument type mismatch - doesn't like defining multiple variables on the same line

Tags: vba, variables

`Compile Error: byref argument type mismatch`

I will occasionally encounter this error when I do something like:
`dim foo, doo, coo as string`

I've found 1 of 2 ways to solve this error:

1. Change the data type to `variant` as in `dim foo, doo, coo as variant`
2. Simply putting each on their own line:

   `dim foo as string`
   `dim doo as string`
   `dim coo as string`

I've seen this twice, specifically when using these variables as parameters in functions. Is this a known bug? Is there something intrinsic to defining multiple variables on the same line that I'm missing?

Comment: `Dim foo, doo, coo As String` means that `foo` and `doo` are `Variant`s.

Comment: `Dim foo As String, doo As String, coo As String`.

Comment: @BigBen well...that is enlightening. For a very long time, I assumed you could simply define multiple variables on the same line without only one 'as' statement.. Thanks for clarifying.